# How do I launch a "Ready to Start" game on an Xbox One S?

Tags: xbox-one

Yesterday I bought an Xbox One S with a few games. I'm installing Call of Duty: Modern Warfare Remastered, and it's at the point where the home screen says "Ready to Start". I click on the tile, but I just get told "You need to install the game or app for this", which I'm already in the process of doing.

From reading online, when it says "Ready to Play" I should be able to at least open the game and play something (whether it's a tutorial level or watch some cutscenes or something), but until the download is complete, I can't really do anything.

I'm happy to wait, as it'll only be another 15 minutes or so until it's done, but I'm wondering if I'm misunderstanding something about the Xbox One and the "FastStart" feature.

Comment: No, your assumptions are correct, that is how it should work and how I experienced it in the past.

Comment: @Eric well it got to about 75% installed, then I was finally able to play it. This was after it changed to "Ready to Play" at about 40% or so (I think?)